# How C header files import win32api functions?

Tags: c, winapi, reverse-engineering

short question.

When I do:

```
#include <windows.h>

CreateProcess(..)
```

---

How does the  header file knows to connect me to the correct dll?

Is there a dictionary inside those header files that maps each win32api function to the relevant dll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The headers only contain declarations for the API functions, not their definitions. The definitions are found by linking the appropriate libraries.

For example, copy the following into a `.c` file:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Hello World", L"", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Try to compile it on the Visual Studio Command Prompt with the command `cl example.c`. You will see the error message:

```
example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxW@16 referenced in function _main
```

Note that compilation itself actually succeeds; it's the linker that complains about the missing function definition.

If you instead compile it with `cl example.c /link user32.lib`, the linker will find the definition for `MessageBox`. You could also just `link example.obj user32.lib`.

So, to answer your question: the headers don't need to know which DLLs the functions are in because the project is required to provide the appropriate library references.  Fortunately, the MSDN documentation for Windows API functions will tell you which DLL the function is in and which library to link.

Comment: You really opened my eyes here. How why isn't it like that in gcc? Can't cl.exe do linking automatically? Another question, so to my understanding, inorder to use the functions of a certain dll, you need the corresponding header file that will contain all function signatures and related structures?

Comment: @TrigosinDarom The compiler / implementation may implicitly link certain libraries by default, so GCC may not require you to specify an additional library that MSVC does require, and vice versa.

Accessing a DLL's exported functions depends on the method you use to link to the DLL. See [this article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll) for more details.

Comment: @TrigosinDarom Different DLLs implement different functions, and provide separate import lib files to find those functions. Do you really expect the linker to know every every lib file on the system? No. So you have to tell it which lib file(s) you are actually interested in it looking at. So, to use a given DLL function **statically**, you need its declaration (header file) AND its definition (lib file).  If you were to instead import the DLL function dynamically at runtime using `GetProcAddress()`, that would be a whole different matter (no lib file needed).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: header file does NOT know about the DLL that implements those functions.

Typically, you would specify those DLLs to the linker.

Alternatively, you can use `#pragma comment(lib, “XXX”)` to do that for you.

Comment: if you really specify `.dll` somehow(`/DELAYLOAD`) you'll need `GetModuleHandle` 
   `GetProcAddress`

Answer (score 2):

Header files don't know or care where functions are located.  A header file simply declares the functions.  When you call functions in your code, the compiler simply emits references in the object file that note which functions are being called.

After the compiler is finished, it is the linker that then brings all of the object files together and updates the function references to point at the actual implementations, whether they are located in DLLs or not.  So you have to supply the linker, not the compiler, with the necessary information it needs to know which object files and DLL import files to look at where the functions can be found.

Most project makefiles for common compiler/linker toolchains will usually include a default set of DLL import files for the linker to look at, for instance `kernel32.lib` (where `CreateProcess(A|W)` can be resolved from), `user32.lib`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to statically link to a DLL (yes, statically), you link against a .lib library that declares the functions to be imported.

The VS compiler supports a #pragma that tells the linker to use a certain .lib file (using specific path resolution rules). Such a #pragma is present in the Windows header files.

Now at load time, the system looks for the DLL file that was named in the .lib file, using specific path resolution rules, and matches the imported prototypes to the functions exported by the DLL.

---

Hence, the dictionary that maps functions to DLLs, is in fact made of the .lib files referred to by the header files, for each DLL.